# Quotation marks in a block quote that consists entirely of quoted speech

Tags: quotations, quotation-marks

I know that you wouldn't normally enclose a block quote with quotation marks; but what I can't seem to find out is what to do if the quoted material consists entirely of quoted speech.

For example, this is the original quote (from the Bible):

> Then Daniel praised the God of heaven and said: 
>   "Praise be to the name of God for ever and ever;
>   wisdom and power are his."

Which of the following is correct?

> In Daniel 2:20, Daniel sings a song of praise to God:
>
> > Praise be to the name of God for ever and ever;
> >     wisdom and power are his.

or:

> In Daniel 2:20, Daniel sings a song of praise to God:
>
> > "Praise be to the name of God for ever and ever;
> >     wisdom and power are his."

Many thanks, and apologies if this has been asked before; I did search, but couldn't find anything!

Comment: This is a stylistic choice. I haven't checked, but it would not surprise me if different style guides specified different methods (if they even mention it). My method would be to leave the citation out of the block quotes, but immediately above them, as a sort of title. Issue vanishes, and inner quotes are only necessary when the material itself uses them.

Answer (score 1):

That passage is too short to be made into a block quote. Usually you would need to be quoting at least 4 lines of text.
https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/03/

The best way to quote that passage is to write (directly as a part of the narrative structure): Then Daniel praised the God of heaven and said: "Praise be to the name of God for ever and ever; wisdom and power are his." (Daniel 2:20)

If you are quoting a long passage and need a block quote format, do not enclose the block in your own quotation marks, but do keep the quotation marks as they appear in the original passage.